# Change .htaccess directory in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5

Hell folks,

In my project the .htaccess file is placed in the project root directory.

I want it placed in some other directory say '/public/setupfiles' and the project should be able to access it.

Is it possible? if yes thn how?

Comment: It depends what you are trying to do. Generally, you can't simply move `.htaccess` files from one directory to another. It's not the "project" that accesses it, but the webserver (Apache / LiteSpeed). `/public/setupfiles` - is that part of the URL-path? (I would guess not, in which case you are probably still going to need a minimal `.htaccess` in the root directory.)

Comment: I am just trying to keep all setup files required for the project in one place.

and yes, the complete path would be '/var/www/html/laravelproject/public/setupfiles/.htaccess'.

But i got ur point. :)